# How to resize a inner divs according to resize of outer div?

Tags: jquery, html

**HTML:**

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner1"></div>
  <div class="inner2"></div>
</div>
```

---

**CSS:**

```
.outer {
position: absolute;
float: left;
min-height: 120px;
min-width: 180px;
height: 160px;
width: 200px;
}
.inner1{
cursor: pointer;
min-height: 25px;
}
.inner2
{
width: 100%;
height: 85%;
min-height: 120px;
min-width: 180px;
resize: none;
margin: 0px;
}
```

---

`inner2` get re-size automatically when i re-size outer which can be re-size only.and inner1 as fixed height and width.it is like header.
i do not want to re-size `inner2` explicitly. inner2 should re-size according to 
outer div 
Can somebody help me.
check dis http://jsfiddle.net/gHLgt/1/

Comment: plz provide ur code on here or put in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: <div class="outer">
<div class="inner1"></div>
<div class="inner2"></div>
</div>

Answer (score 2):

> I think this may be what you need.
>
> **HTML:**
>
> ```
>  
> <div class="main"> 
>     <div class="header"></div>
>     <div class="innerMain">
>         <div class="content"></div> 
>     </div>
> </div>
> ```
>
> **CSS:**
>
> ```
>   .innerMain {
>     min-height: 120px;
>     min-width: 180px;
>     height: 160px;
>     width: 200px;
>     border:1px solid red;
>     padding: 3px; 
>   }
>   .header{
>     min-height: 120px;
>     min-width: 180px;
>     cursor: pointer;
>     min-height: 25px;
>     border:1px solid green;
>     display: block; 
>   } 
>   .content {
>     height: 100%;
>     resize: none;
>     outline: 3px solid yellow;
>   }
>   .main{
>     width: auto;
>     display: inline-block;
>     border:1px solid black; 
>   }
> ```
>
> **SCRIPT:**
>
> ```
>   $(".innerMain").resizable();
> ```
>
> jsfiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/gHLgt/6/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gHLgt/7/ can u check this. I want that "content" div is editable. or i want textarea instead of that. if i put teatarea its not working properly. or if i put contenteditable=true.. again its not working u can check above jsfiddle

Comment: Here you go http://jsfiddle.net/gHLgt/10/. You don't have to replace the div with text area or make it editable. Just add textarea inside it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set a width on `inner1` and `inner2` if you don't want them to be resized.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 .inner2
    {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    height:100%;
    resize: none;
    margin: -25px 0 0 0px;
    border:3px solid yellow;
    }
```

Comment: inner2 will cover inner1 in this case which i dont want. i want both the div inner1 and inner2 visible

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try like this, made some changes in the css,

```
   .outer
        {
            position: absolute;
            float: left;
            min-height: 120px;
            min-width: 180px;
            height: 160px;
            width: 200px;
            border: 2px solid #000;
        }

        .inner1
        {
            cursor: pointer;
            min-height: 20px;
            height: 20%;
            background-color: #FF0000;
        }

        .inner2
        {
            height: 80%;
            min-height: 100px;
            min-width: 180px;
            resize: none;
            margin: 0px;
            background-color: #01DF01;
        }
```

Comment: in this case inner1 size is also increasing i want fixed inner1 and resizable inner2

Comment: yeah... You have first div with fixed height and second is in percentage. At some particular point second div will have issues.

If you could resize the second div like, this.style.width = (this.clientWidth - 25)+ "px" or something like reassigning.